# lengths of sides in golden ratio isosceles triangles

Tags: golden-ratio

The figure below shows three different isosceles triangles. every triangle is either 36-36-108 or 36-72-72. The base of the outermost triangle has length $\phi$.

[image]
Find the lengths of both lines AT and MT.

Can someone please help me figure this out? What I'm thinking so far is that $1+\phi=\phi^2$ has roots which are the golden ratio.

I found this image online (on wikipedia) and i think it is the solution but i don't know how to solve it or actually get these values

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown on Wikipedia's article about golden ratio (letters in the blockquote indicate points on the picture provided by Wikipedia):

> If angle BCX = α, then XCA = α because of the bisection, and CAB = α because of the similar triangles; ABC = 2α from the original isosceles symmetry, and BXC = 2α by similarity. The angles in a triangle add up to 180°, so 5α = 180, giving α = 36°. So the angles of the golden triangle are thus 36°-72°-72°. The angles of the remaining obtuse isosceles triangle AXC (sometimes called the golden gnomon) are 36°-36°-108°.

From the given above (in the question) $AH=TH= \phi$ and $m(\angle AHT)=36°$, So by using [Law of cosines](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines):

$${AT}^2={AH}^2+{TH}^2-2(AH)(TH)(\cos {\angle AHT}) \\  {AT}^2={\phi}^2+{\phi}^2-2(\phi)(\phi)(\cos {36°}) \\ {AT}^2=2{\phi}^2-2\phi^2 \cdot \cos {36°} \\ {AT}^2=2 \left( {\frac {3+ \sqrt 5}{2}} \right) -2 \left( {\frac {3+ \sqrt 5}{2}} \right) (\cos {36°})=1 \\ AT=\sqrt 1 =1$$
Similarly, 
$${AC}^2=2 {\phi}^2-2{\phi}^2(\cos 108°)={\phi}^4 \\ AC = {\phi}^2$$
Now you know it, law of cosines is the trick in such questions.

I hope my answer helps you !

### Another solution:-

You can use trigonometrical functions to get the height of any of the two triangles and then use Pythagoras theorem to find other sides (in each triangle).

Comment: thanks os much, this does help but i just haven't learned law of cosines yet. is there another way to solve?

Comment: There are some other ways but you will still need to use trigonometrical functions; however I will tell you if I found something different.

Comment: @user477465 , I searched for another way but it seems that you will always have to use trigonometrical functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply this formula to your first picture `1 + ϕ = ϕ*ϕ`
then the length of AT + ϕ = ϕ*ϕ
so, length of AT equals `ϕ*ϕ - ϕ`

Comment: if it's isosceles why isn't hte answer that AT is just $\phi$?

Comment: Because HA has length ϕ, if AT also has length ϕ, it would not be isosceles

Comment: so then why isnt the length of AT=1 like the last picture suggests

Comment: also how do you know these values?

Comment: ϕ in picture1 is NOT equal to  ϕ in picture 2

Comment: If the length of XB,(last picture) would be something else than 1, also AC would be something else, and  ϕ is just a variable.